# "This module will be removed in 0.20.", DeprecationWarning in spyder

Tags: python, spyder, deprecation-warning

I am new to programming. I am trying to run a script I downloaded on spyder. I am getting

Deprecation Warning: *This module was deprecated in version 0.18 in favor of the model_selection module into which all the refactored classes and functions are moved. Also note that the interface of the new CV iterators are different from that of this module. This module will be removed in 0.20.*

Please help me understand and resolve this

Comment: A deprecation warning means that the package has been marked for retirement - it will be removed/unsupported in the future. As it is a warning, you are just being told that you should switch from whatever module you are using now to `model_selection`.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same warning in sklearn.

Instead of using **from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split**

use

**from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split**